# Multiple game servers on one dedicated machine with different IP’s

Tags: server

I apologize if this is not the proper place to ask this question but I am hoping that if you folks cannot help then you would know of someone or somewhere to send me to get the answers that I have desperately been searching for. I have currently purchased a dedicated machine from a hosting service.  I am running Windows 2019 on the machine. I do not have much experience with dedicated machines.  I am currently running 2 Rust game servers on the same IP with different ports but the servers are fairly laggy.  I am wanting to run the servers with 2 different IP's which I have 5 usable IP's.  Please help me as I have been searching and trying to find the answer to these issues.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If the question is if you can run your server machine with two different IPs, that is something to ask your provider. If you are doing your own installation, try serverfault.com - Yet, I doubt something like that would solve your performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

This Rust server documentation https://www.bestrusthosting.com/guides/how-to-configure-your-rust-server-all-options-explained/

Says you can set the server bind IP address in the console or config file

> `+server ip x.x.x.x`
>
> This is also important. As you’d expect, it changes the IP address your users will connect to. However, less obvious is the fact it should be set to 0.0.0.0 for most setups. This will let it automatically adjust to your current IP address. The only time you need to set it manually is if you have multiple IPs.

That said, once the server is started/bound to a port, it doesn't care what port/IP is being used, it's just talking to a "socket".

Outside a few very rare cases -like a DDoS attack saturating a network interface- there should be no practical difference between using 2 ports on the same IP or 1 port on 2 IPs.

I suspect you've mis-diagnosed the bottleneck.

Try opening whatever performance monitoring tools you have access to and checking CPU/Disk/Memory utilisation.